# Extreme points for capacitated flow polytope

Tags: reference-request, network-flow, polyhedra

Given a network as a directed acyclic graph with a source and sink, and non-negative edge capacities, I am interested in the extreme source-sink flows. More formally, I am interested in a characterization of the extreme points (vertices) of the capacitated flow polytope. Can someone provide me a reference to this problem or state the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at chapter 13, namely "Path and flow polyhedra and total unimodularity", of [Alexander Schrijver](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Elex/)'s masterpiece "Combinatorial Optimization - Polyhedra and Efficiency". You will find characterizations based on cuts, which are the dual of flows in digraphs. This is linked to the famous [max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem).